# Is it possible to get the index of the top left face corner for each quad in a mesh in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have some geometry made up of quads and I want to select the upper left face corner of each face. Up as in +Z in world space and left relative to the face normal if that makes sense. Is this possible? or something similar?

To add some more information, the geometry is not made procedurally. It's modeled by me. I want to alter it using geometry nodes and I've found that the face corners have seemingly random indices so I can't rely on corner index 0 being in the same place on each quad.

Comment: i would say...it depends. if you made the quads from a grid - for sure. Since you didn't tell or show us how you made it - i would recommend giving us the necessary information and improve your question

Comment: Thank you, I have added some more information and hopefully covered what you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want.. you may be looking for another projection. This group:

[image]

- (Where Object-Z is 'high',) finds the second-highest corner in each face.
- If the next anticlockwise corner is higher, selects that. Else, selects this.
- Marks the selection as `True`.

Here, cubes are instanced on 'top left' corners:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much 